# Proof of Existence of Minimization using Minimizng sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

I have to prove the existence of a solution for the following problem
$ min J(u)=f(u)+(\gamma / 2)(|\nabla u|_{L^2 (\Omega)}^2 +\beta \int_{\Omega} M_{\kappa} (|u|^2) $
Where
$ f:H^1(\Omega)\ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+  is \ weaker lower \ semicontinious$
$p\in [0,1] , {\displaystyle \ell } \subset L^2(\Omega)$is closed but not necessarily bounded ,$\Omega$ is a bounded domain with the Lebesgue measure and
$M_\kappa(u):\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ \

$ M_{\kappa} (u)=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{p}{2} \frac{u}{\kappa^{2-p}}+ (1-\frac{p}{2} )\kappa^p   for \ u \in [o,\kappa^2]\\
u^{\frac{p}{2} \  for   \ u \ in [\kappa^2 , \infty]}
\end{Bmatrix} $
and  $u\in H^1(\Omega)\cap  {\displaystyle \ell }   $

to proof this we had used minimizing sequence $\{ u_k\}$  and decomposed $u\in L^2(\omega) $ into sum of two functions $u=u^0+u^1$ where \
$u^0=\frac{1}{||\Omega||} \int_\Omega u \ dx $ and $u^1 =\int_\Omega  u \  dx =0  $
and then we proof that  $\int_{\Omega} M_{\kappa} (|{u^0}_k|^2) \  ,  |\nabla {u^0}_k|_{L^2 (\Omega)}^2  , \int_{\Omega} M_{\kappa} (|{u^1}_k|^2) \  ,  |\nabla {u^1}_k|_{L^2 (\Omega)}^2    $ are bounded \
so Hence $\{u^k\} $ is bounded in $H^1(\Omega)$
my question is
why we can need to decompose u like that and why we can  guarantee that such decomposition exists .Also how can we proof the boundedness of  $ {u^1}_k$.

Comment: Also try to end sentences with a period (not a line break)

Comment: This decomposition exists always. $(u^1_k$) is bounded because $\int M_\kappa(u^1_k)$ is bounded.

Comment: The decomposition is to get a bounded sequence in $H^1$, not just a sequence of functions for which the gradients are bounded in $L^2$

Comment: I added extra informations above